# Asking for a reference from a company I was fired from

Tags: new-job, hiring-process, termination

I received a job offer 1 week ago, I've accepted it but today I was fired from my current employer.

Just 2 days ago, my future employer asked for my current employer's reference and I provided them with HR details. I requested for them to wait 1 week as I would be handing my notice in then. Now there is no need to wait one week but I'm worried my future employer may think that I was fired and may reconsider hiring me.

Should I be upfront with my future employer and let them know I was fired and then can now contact my employer for a reference. Or should I 'beat around the bush' and just tell them they can now contact my employer without mentioning being let go.

My main concern is they will reconsider hiring me due to the termination.

Comment: Were you fired before or after giving notice?

Comment: Before, I was not able to give my notice. I planned to hand it next week.

Comment: Did they have an inkling that you might be leaving?

Comment: Do you know if the hiring company waited or just contacted them? I.e. Why were you fired?

Comment: I was fired for under-performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you were fired for misconduct or security policy violation, I believe that information is not relevant to your future employer now.

They interviewed you and you cleared and accepted the job offer. They may only need to check your working tenure with your previous organization, nothing more.

If the current employer would not have terminated your contract, you would have left through normal process anyways - so for the future employer, it really should not matter. However, be clear in your communication with the future employer - let them know that:

1. You were let go before you could submit your resignation, and they can check for reference now.
2. Now that you don't need to serve the notice period, you can join prior to the agreed date, if they are willing to take you onboard.

Comment: I was not fired for either of those two, so my future employer does not need to know my contract was terminated but you have advised it's better for me to do so and be upfront? Also, would my current employer tell my future employer I was terminated? Lastly, how badly will my future employer conceive the termination?

Comment: @Ali Well, since you already told them to hold on, as you need to resign and serve notice, and now suddenly (because of the termination) you're available - may create some confusions. As you confirmed the reason is performance - your future employer would not bother about that. Nothing to be gained by hiding, rather showing your cards will gain you some trust and confidence.

Comment: "Also, would my current employer tell my future employer I was terminated?" Vastly depends on location. Example: In India, if you're terminated, that'll be written in BOLD and CAPITALS in your "relieving letter" as a permanent record, is some other countries, even revealing it verbally might be illegal.

Comment: "Lastly, how badly will my future employer conceive the termination" - Most likely, the'll let this pass anyways.

Comment: @SouravGhosh as you mentioned in comments (and I see m to remember too) it might be illegal in some countries to let the other company know OP was fired. So maybe OP should try to find out this first before he volunteers this information willingly to his new employer

Comment: Thank you very much Sourav for your insight. I'm from the UK so maybe the laws are more restrictive here. I would always want to be upfront with my future employer and I'm glad your points suggest so.

Comment: I believe in the UK, a reference can include if an employee was terminated.

Comment: @Ali You are correct check [here](https://www.gov.uk/work-reference) to see what can or cannot be included in a reference since you are in the UK. It's actually unusual in the UK to include negative details in a reference for example that you were sacked for performance reasons as the company would need to have evidence of this otherwise you could claim damages to reputation in court. Normally companies will omit any details just saying your start and end date.